# How to make book easy to find the chapter by side view?

Tags: book-design

It is hard to explain my question, so I put the picture here.

[image]

I want to put chapter number (such as 3) with dark background in my book, then it helps to find the location the specific chapter from side view.

Can someone give me a help, how to do it?

John

Comment: The keyword is "thumb index".

Comment: Some prior questions can be found using the `thumb-index` tag: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-index